# In LINQ to SQL, How to return datetime in ISO 8601 String, IETF String or timestamp?

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, json, datetime

In [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL), how can I convert this format: **"VDate(1253451600000+0200)V"** 
to an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string, IETF string or timestamp format?

I'm using [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) JSON-Enabled and Ajax-Enabled web service.

Comment: What does the value VDate(1253451600000+0200)V mean?  What generates dates of that format?

Answer (score 0):

Run it through a DataContractJsonSerializer

```
ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DateTime)); 
DateTime dt = ser.ReadObject(ms) as DateTime;
ms.Close();
```

Now, using this DateTime, do whatever you wish!